# the width of my progress bar is not displayed

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a progress bar using data-attributes and I want this values to update in a setInterval loop with a starting at 0. I think my code is good as my values do the work well, they starts at 0 and ends to the maximum indicated. I also used the function getBoundingClientRect to see the width and it works well in the console so I can't understand why the width still doesn't change. if you could help me, I'll be very gratefull, thank you in advance. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: 0;
        }
        .container
        {
            width: 50%;
            float: right;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
        .progress-holder
        {
            margin: 14px 0 0 -2px;
        }
        .progress-holder li {
            height: 30px;
            margin: 0 0 20px;
            position: relative;
            background: #f8f8f8;
            list-style: none;
        }
        .progress-holder .text {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        abbr[title]
        {
            cursor: help;
        }
        .progress-bar
        {
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            box-shadow: none;
            border-radius: 0;
            overflow: visible;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .load
        {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 30px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background: #e74c3c;
            width: 0%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="container">
        <ul class="progress-holder">
            <li>
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <span class="load" data-width="86"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="text">
                    <abbr title="(eXtensible) HyperText Markup Language">(X)HTML</abbr>
                    <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>
                </span>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <span class="load" data-width="44"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="text">
                    <abbr title="Langage de développement Web orienté client">JAVASCRIPT</abbr>
                </span>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <span class="load" data-width="33"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="text">
                    <abbr title="Hypertext Prepocessor">PHP</abbr>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script>
        let loads = document.getElementsByClassName('load');
        let loadsArray = Array.from(loads);

        loadsArray.forEach(function(element)
        {
            console.log(element);
            let counterStart = 0;
            let data = element.dataset.width;
            let loadedBar = element.getBoundingClientRect();

            let intervalProgress = setInterval(() => {

                counterStart += 1;
                loadedBar.width = counterStart;
                console.log(loadedBar);

                if(counterStart >= data)
                {
                    clearInterval(intervalProgress);
                }
            }, 50);
        });

        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `loadedBar.width = counterStart;` to `element.style.width = counterStart + '%';` (or something similar) because `element.getBoundingClientRect()` can't be edited (or rather doesn't change the element when it is edited).